# Pagenumbering using alphalph package

Tags: packages, page-numbering, appendices

I need to have 'AA' page numbering as my appendix is to large for a single lette 'A', 'B', ... but cannot get it to work.

My try on it is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,final]{report} 

\usepackage{alphalph,etoolbox}

\begin{document} 

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{1}
\section{2}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\renewcommand\thesection{\AlphAlph{\value{section}}}
\appendix

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\AlphAlph` you will need 401 pages in the appendix. Then, the number of pages in the appendix is `OK`. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\pagenumbering` expects a macro that starts with `@` that takes a value like `\AlphAlph`.

For the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@AlphAlph}{}% Check that \@AlphAlph is undefined.
\let\@AlphAlph=\AlphAlph
\makeatother
```

Then the following should work:

```
\pagenumbering{AlphAlph}
```

Comment: @jules Sorry, first version of the answer was crap. Fixed now.